# Execute function(Web Service) after all the values pass in as key, value pairs

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, wsdl

I have two tables:

Table 1(t1):

```
column=> id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
values=>  1, v1, v2, v3
```

Table 2(t2):

```
column=> t1_id, t2.col1, t2.col2
values=> 1, val1, val2
         1, val3, val4
         1, val5, val6
```

I am executing a function(WebService) which takes in key, value pairs(as parameters) in an array For example:

```
array(array("Key" => val1,
            "value" => val2),
      array("key" => val3,
            "value" => val4))
```

I want to do the same by getting the values from the database that is table 2. So, What I did is, fetched the key, value pairs from the data base and stored it as $key, and & $value. Now the function looks like:

```
 array(array("Key" => $key,
            "value" => $value))
```

when I run this, Instead of taking all the key, value pairs and executing after, The function is executing for each key, value pair.

I want to execute the function only all the key, value pairs are in the array.

Comment: You're talking about functions, but all you gave are arrays ? Can you give us the code of your functions ?

Comment: If you want us to help you you need to post all relevant parts of your code.